# Slicing using dplyr based on condition in a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe containing repeated measurements for some individuals, the data.frame looks like this

```
# A tibble: 853 x 5
   ID         Test  N_ind Pheno  Week
   <chr>      <chr> <int> <dbl> <int>
 1 02A01      Int      96     0    12
 2 02A01      Int      96     0    24
 3 02A01      Int      94     0    36
 4 02A01      Int      90     0    48
 7 02A01      Int      78     1    84
 9 02A03      Int      96     0    12
10 02A03      Int      96     0    24
11 02A03      Int      94     0    36
19 02C03      Int      96     1    12
20 0202C03    Int      96     0    24
21 0202C03    Int      94     0    36
22 0202C03    Int      90     0    48
23 02E02      Int      96     0    12
24 02E02      Int      96     0    24
25 02E02      Int      94     1    36
26 02E02      Int      90     1    48
```

I want to subset the data.frame, first grouping by `ID` and then within the group selecting for those individuals with a `1` in the column `Pheno` the lowest `Week` value, but for those individuals with a `0` in the column `Pheno` the highest value in `Week`.

The optimal result should look like this:

```
   ID         Test  N_ind Pheno  Week
   <chr>      <chr> <int> <dbl> <int>
 7 02A01      Int      78     1    84
11 02A03      Int      94     0    36
19 02C03      Int      96     1    12
22 0202C03    Int      90     0    48
25 02E02      Int      94     1    36
```

I have managed to do that for the `1` values but I am stuck in how to do it for the `0` values.

Here is my code:

```
df_sub <- data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(Week, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try -

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(Week == if(all(Pheno == 0)) max(Week) else min(Week[Pheno == 1])) %>%
  ungroup

#   ID      Test  N_ind Pheno  Week
#  <chr>   <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#1 02A01   Int      78     1    84
#2 02A03   Int      94     0    36
#3 02C03   Int      96     1    12
#4 0202C03 Int      90     0    48
#5 02E02   Int      94     1    36
```

If `all` the `Pheno` values in a group are 0 return the max value or else from the `Pheno = 1` values return the minimum one.

Comment: brilliant!! I didn't know I could use `if` and `else` command in `filter`, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
data %>%
  group_by(ID, Pheno) %>%
  filter(case_when(
    Pheno == 1 ~ Week == min(Week),
    Pheno == 0 ~ Week == max(Week)
  )) %>%
  ungroup(Pheno) %>%
  filter(case_when(
    any(Pheno == 1) ~ Pheno == 1,
    all(Pheno == 0) ~ Pheno == 0
  )) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Which results to:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  ID      Test  N_ind Pheno  Week
  <chr>   <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1 02A01   Int      78     1    84
2 02A03   Int      94     0    36
3 02C03   Int      96     1    12
4 0202C03 Int      90     0    48
5 02E02   Int      94     1    36
```

Answer (score 0):

using `dplyr` and `if`, `else` in `filter`,

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(if (Pheno == 0) Week == max(Week)
         else Week == min(Week))

  ID      Test  N_ind Pheno  Week
  <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 02A01   Int      78     1    84
2 02A03   Int      94     0    36
3 02C03   Int      96     1    12
4 0202C03 Int      90     0    48
5 02E02   Int      90     1    48
```

Answer (score 0):

We can first `group_by` ID, then `filter` with the `max` value in Pheno.
After that, we can filter with the conditions you want, separated by an OR `|` statement.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
        filter(Pheno==max(Pheno))%>%
        filter(Pheno==0 & Week==min(Week)|Pheno==1 & Week==max(Week))

# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   ID [5]
  ID      Test  N_ind Pheno  Week
  <chr>   <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1 02A01   Int      78     1    84
2 02A03   Int      96     0    12
3 02C03   Int      96     1    12
4 0202C03 Int      96     0    24
5 02E02   Int      90     1    48
```